# lwjgl UnsatisfiedLink error

Tags: java, netbeans, lwjgl

I know this may seem like a duplicate but throughout the examples I have seem I must be doing something wrong still.

I am using Netbeans 8.0.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1865)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1119)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:73)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:66)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:95)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:112)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:132)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer$1.run(AppGameContainer.java:39)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.<clinit>(AppGameContainer.java:36)
    at Engine.main(Engine.java:33)
```

Is my error which i know from research is just the path isn't set. I went into `Properties > Libraries` and i have a Library `LWJGL` which has multiple .jar's in it, including lwjgl.jar. I also have gone to `Properties > Run` which is where i believe my problem is. I have made a folder in `C:\LWJGL\` that contains the lwjgl.jar aswell. My VM Options are `-Djava.library.path=C:\LWJGL\`.

I know i must be missing something here in regards to where is it looking for the native files or something? After reading through other posts i think my problem is the location of the native files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java.library.path` takes the path to the natives (extensions `.dll`, `.so`, `.dylib`), not the jar file. You have to point it directly to the folder where you have stored these files; it won't work when they are in a subfolder. The LWJGL zip file you downloaded will most likely contain a `native` folder that contains these files.

Comment: Unfortunately this is all i had in the lwjgl.zip http://puu.sh/lGGpK/c57f08c0b5.jpg

Comment: ahhh, i seemed to had only downloaded the .jar in the zip. I went out and found another download that has things like native, jar, doc and res. So in the build path of the project you want it to go directly to the native files? -Djava.library.path=C:\lwjgl-2.8.3\native\windows\